# Drop down menu not showing JSON array when new row added dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, json, dropdown

I'm working on dynamically adding new rows and delete new rows with SELECT option. The dynamic row adding and deleting works but the drop down menu doesn't seem to show the JSON array when new row is added. Only the first two static drop down menus shows the JSON array option. Can anyone help figure which part of my code is wrong? Below are my codes and the screenshot:

**JavaScript:**

```
<script>
/////////////////ADD and DELETE ROWS///////////////


/************add new row dymnically******************/
$(document).ready(function(){  
      var i=1;  
      $('#add').click(function(){  
           i++;  
           $('#dynamic_field').append('<tr id="row'+i+'">'+
           '<td>'+
                    '<select class="pcode" name="project_code[]" >'+
                    '</select>'+
           '</td>'+                                                            
           '<td><button type="button" name="remove" id="'+i+'" class="btn btn_remove">Delete Row</button></td></tr>');  
      });  

/**************Remove row****************/    
      $(document).on('click', '.btn_remove', function(){  
           var button_id = $(this).attr("id");   
           $('#row'+button_id+'').remove();  
      });  

 });  



 ////////////SHOW JSON DATA ON MULTIPLE DROP DOWN MENU/////////////

    $(".pcode").each(function() {

    $(this).empty();


    $(this).append('<option selected="true" disabled>Choose Project Code</option>');
    $(this).prop('selectedIndex', 0); //Default Selected Option

    const url = 'api_redcap.php'; //JSON Data source

    $.getJSON(url, function (data) {
      $.each(data, function (key, entry) {
        $(".pcode").append($('<option></option>').attr('value', entry.project_code).text(entry.project_code)); // Populate dropdown with list of project code
      })
    });

        });
</script>
```

**HTML code:**

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <table id="dynamic_field">

        <tr>
            <td>
            <select class="pcode" name="project_code[]">
            </select>
            </td>
            <td>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>    
            <select class="pcode" name="project_code[]">
            </select>
            </td>
            <td>
            <button type="button" name="add" id="add">Add Row</button>
            </td>
        </tr>

    </table>

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
    </form>
```

HTML Screenshot

[image]

Comment: the `select` is not getting populated because of the json load function getting called before the `select` is attached to the `DOM`. So, a different approach would be to call a function inside your `$(document).ready()` to populate the `select` with data after it has been attached to `DOM`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Les88, For example I use static array, You can make json call with my bindOption() function and get data from your service call.

You bind the select tag but there is no code written for binding options inside it i modified it so, Kindly look below solution and let me know is it work for you?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){  
      var i=1;  
      $('#add').click(function(){  
           i++;  
           $('#dynamic_field').append('<tr id="row'+i+'">'+
           '<td>'+
                    '<select class="pcode" name="project_code[]" >'+
                     bindOption() +'</select>'+
           '</td>'+                                                            
           '<td><button type="button" name="remove" id="'+i+'" class="btn btn_remove">Delete Row</button></td></tr>');  
      });  

      $(document).on('click', '.btn_remove', function(){  
           var button_id = $(this).attr("id");   
           $('#row'+button_id+'').remove();  
      });  
      
        $(".pcode").each(function() {
           $(this).find('option').remove();
           $(this).append(bindOption());
        })

 });  

function bindOption(){
    var options = '<option selected="true" disabled>Choose Project Code</option>';
    var serviceArray= new Array("Living Room","Dining Room","Bedroom(s)","Family Room","Kitchen","Den","Hallway(s)","Ste(s)","Bathroom","Landing(s)");
    for (var i = 0; i < serviceArray.length; i++) {
        options += '<option value="' + serviceArray[i] + '">' + serviceArray[i] + '</option>';
    }
    return options;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" method="post">
    <table id="dynamic_field">

        <tr>
            <td>
            <select class="pcode" name="project_code[]">
            </select>
            </td>
            <td>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>    
            <select class="pcode" name="project_code[]">
            </select>
            </td>
            <td>
            <button type="button" name="add" id="add">Add Row</button>
            </td>
        </tr>

    </table>

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
    </form>
```

Comment: Thanks. yours work with the static but how do i insert my JSON array into your bindoption function?

Comment: in  bindOption() function call your  $.getJSON(url, function (data) {
      $.each(data, function (key, entry) {
        $(".pcode").append($('<option></option>').attr('value', entry.project_code).text(entry.project_code)); // Populate dropdown with list of project code
      })
    });
method

Comment: instead of using my bindOption() use function bindOption(){
    var options = '<option selected="true" disabled>Choose Project Code</option>';
    $.getJSON(url, function (data) {
         $.each(data, function (key, entry) {
        options += '<option value="'  + entry.project_code +  '">' + entry.project_code + '</option>';
     })
 })
    return options;
}

Comment: you are Welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply achieve this by

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
 const url = 'api_redcap.php'; //JSON Data source
 function getOptionsHtml() {
     var html = '<option selected="true" disabled>Choose Project Code</option>';
     $.getJSON(url, function (data) {
         $.each(data, function (key, entry) {
             html += '<option value="' + entry.project_code + '">' + entry.project_code + '</option>';
         })
     });
     return html;
 }
 var opionsHtml = getOptionsHtml();
 var i = 1;
 $('#add').click(function () {
     i++;
     $('#dynamic_field').append('<tr id="row' + i + '">' +
         '<td>' +
         '<select class="pcode" name="project_code[]" >' +
         opionsHtml+
         '</select>' +
         '</td>' +
         '<td><button type="button" name="remove" id="' + i + '" class="btn btn_remove">Delete Row</button></td></tr>');
 });

 /**************Remove row****************/
 $(document).on('click', '.btn_remove', function () {
     var button_id = $(this).attr("id");
     $('#row' + button_id + '').remove();
 });

 $(".pcode").each(function () {
     $(this).empty();
     $(this).append(opionsHtml);
 });
});
```

Comment: It doesn't work. The SELECT shows only "Choose Project Code" but not the json array.

Comment: Can you please share your JSON Data ?